# Alternatives for KeyManager & JKSKeyManager in Spring-Security-SAML2-Service-Provider 6.1.3?

Tags: java, spring-security, migration, saml, key-management

I am currently working on a project that makes use of Spring's SAML2 security module. The project is using an older, end-of-life version, **`spring-security-saml2-core 1.0.10.RELEASE`**. As part of the project's maintenance and to keep the dependencies up-to-date, I'm trying to migrate to **`spring-security-saml2-service-provider 6.1.3`**.

I was able to migrate most of the components and services except for classes related to key management, specifically **`JKSKeyManager`** and **`KeyManager`**. In the older version, these classes are crucial for SAML authentication to work. I searched through the official documentation, forums, and online resources but couldn't find any clear alternatives or solutions.

I'm looking for alternative classes or configurations in **`spring-security-saml2-service-provider 6.1.3`** that can replace **`JKSKeyManager`** and **`KeyManager`** to maintain the same functionality. Any help in pointing to relevant classes, methods, or documentation is greatly appreciated.